# How to make changes to Pawn.cpp Unreal?

Tags: c++, unreal, source-code

I am trying to figure out a problem related to CableComponents.

As part of my learning and problem identification I'm trying to place some UE_LOGs/Debug Messages within Pawn.cpp and CableComponent.cpp

These changes are not reflected when the c++ code is compiled within unreal. which is consistent with Unreal only building project code.

So My question is, how can I make these changes to the source code and have them be used?

Alternatively, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

**The reason i'm trying to do this**

- I'm trying to figure out how often the dynamic data of UCableComponent is recalculated compared to the rendering update of APawn.

Comment: Can you give us more details about the specific problem you're trying to troubleshoot? We might be able to suggest approaches you can take that don't involve editing this file to insert log messages.

Comment: Edited to include intended usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make changes to the code of the Unreal Engine you have to recompile the Unreal Engine. See the [documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Development/BuildingUnrealEngine/index.html) to find out how to do this.